# Ubuntu 18.04 does not see USB keyboard and mouse

Tags: ubuntu, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have been looking on this forum for quite a long time and I havent found any answer to my question yet. I cant see my USB mouse and keyboard.

Nothing helps or is only bundle of tasks leading nowhere. Sometimes is work, sometimes my USB devices just disconnect.

> lsusb

DOES NOT find my devices when they are disconnected.

Thanks for simple answering my question.

Comment: What happens if you unplug them and then plug them into different USB ports? Are you using a USB hub, or are they plugged in directly?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd be willing to bet that it's a USB version 2, verses USB version 3 issue. If you were to move your keyboard, and mouse to a different `USB` port. You may find everything begins to work (again?). Lastly, you should always ensure that your Keyboard, and Mouse do *not* share the same (`USB`) port with other devices. This is also a frequent cause for your problem.

If this solution doesn't solve your problem. Please post the contents of [dmesg](https://manpage.me/?dmesg).